# pdfpages: add a figure title to LOF without figure number

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,justified,nohyper,notoc]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\includepdf[pages=-,
addtolist={
1,figure,FIGUREA,fA,
2,table,TABLEA,tA,
3,figure,FIGUREB,fA,
4,table,TABLEB,tB},
pagecommand={}]{PDFfile.pdf}

\end{document}
```

generates the following:

```
List of Figures
1 FIGUREA 4
2 FIGUREB 6
List of Tables
1 TABLEA 5
2 TABLEB 7
```

What I would like to get, instead, is the following:

```
List of Figures
1 FIGUREA 4
  FIGUREB 6
List of Tables
1 TABLEA 5
  TABLEB 7
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use \listofigures.  Just list the figures however you want them named or formatted.  Note that the title was generated using \section* or \chapter* (depending on the document class) and the formatting is handled using \l@figure and \l@table.  Oh, and \numline is typically added by \caption (see the aux file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

One needs to replace code

```
\includepdf[pages=-,
addtolist={
1,figure,FIGUREA,fA,
2,table,TABLEA,tA,
3,figure,FIGUREB,fA,
4,table,TABLEB,tB},
pagecommand={}]{PDFfile.pdf}
```

with

```
\addtomylist{%
\lofadd{3}{FIGUREB}{fB}
\lotadd{4}{TABLEB}{tB}}

\includepdf[pages=-,
addtolist={
1,figure,FIGUREA,fA,
2,table,TABLEA,tA},
pagecommand={\mylist}]{PDFfile.pdf}
```

In the code above  we have

- `\lo<X>add`: with `X=f` figure and `X=t` for table.
- `\lo<X>add{A1}{A2}{A3}`: `A1` is the number of included page, `A2` the title (caption) of figure or table and `A3` is a label.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,justified,nohyper,notoc]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}

\newcounter{pagectr}
\newcommand{\loftadd}[5]{%
\ifnum\value{pagectr}=#1
    \refstepcounter{#2}%
    \label{#3}
    \addcontentsline{#4}{#2}{%
        \protect\numberline {}{\protect\ignorespaces \protect\ignorespaces #5}}%
\fi}
\newcommand{\lofadd}[3]{\loftadd{#1}{figure}{#3}{lof}{#2}}
\newcommand{\lotadd}[3]{\loftadd{#1}{table}{#3}{lot}{#2}}
\newcommand{\addtomylist}[1]{%
    \setcounter{pagectr}{0}%
    \gdef\mylist{%
        \stepcounter{pagectr}%
        #1}%
}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\addtomylist{%
\lofadd{3}{FIGUREB}{fB}
\lotadd{4}{TABLEB}{tB}}

\includepdf[pages=-,
addtolist={
1,figure,FIGUREA,fA,
2,table,TABLEA,tA},
pagecommand={\mylist}]{dvips.pdf}

\end{document}
```